# Is it possible to use python to establish a putty ssh session and send some input?

Tags: python, session, ssh, network-programming, putty

Fist of all, due to Company Policy, Paramiko, or installing anything that requires administrative access to local machine it right out; otherwise I would have just done that.

All I have to work with is python with standard libraries & putty.

I am attempting to automate some tedious work that involves logging into a network device (usually Cisco, occasionally Alcatel-Lucent, or Juniper), running some show commands, and saving the data. (I am planning on using some other scripts to pull data from this file, parse it, and do other things, but that should be irrelevant to the task of retrieving the data.) I know this can be done with telnet, however I need to do this via ssh.

My thought is to use putty's logging ability to record output from a session to a file. I would like to use Python to establish a putty session, send scripted log-in and show commands, and then close the session. Before I set out on this crusade, does anyone know of any way to do this? The closest answers I have found to this all suggest to use Paramiko, or other python ssh library; I am looking for a way to do this given the constraints I am under.

The end-result would ideal be able to be used as a function, so that I can iterate through hundreds of devices from a list of ip addresses.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: @Jakuje:
'First of all, due to Company Policy, Paramiko, or installing anything that requires administrative access to local machine it right out; otherwise I would have just done that."

Comment: @khajah:
Great! Could I please have some extrapolation on how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use paramiko, and Putty is all you get so the correct tool is actually not Putty - it's his little brother [Plink - you can download it here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) 
Plink is the command line tool for Putty and you can your python script to call it using `os.system("plink.exe [options] username@server.com [command])`

See MAN Page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/plink)

Hope it will help,

Liron

Comment: Thank you! This has the functionality I need!